# Why can not push image to my private registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

**service:**

```
docker service create --name registry --secret domain.crt --secret domain.key --constraint 'node.labels.registry==true' --mount type=volume,src=registry-data,dst=/var/lib/registry --mount type=bind,src=/etc/docker/auth,dst=/auth -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/run/secrets/domain.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/run/secrets/domain.key -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd --publish published=443,target=443 --replicas 1 registry:2
```

**login:**

```
docker login lcy_docker1.example
```

Username: admin

Password:

Login Succeeded

**push:**

```
docker tag hello-world lcy_docker1.example/hello-world
docker push lcy_docker1.example/hello-world

# The push refers to repository [lcy_docker1.example/hello-world]
# Get https:///v2/: http: no Host in request URL
```

Why can't push to my private registry?

Comment: What version of Docker are you using?

Comment: docker-ce. 18 help me.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove "_" underscore string from domain.
lcy_docker1.example -> lcydocker1.example

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34975

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didnt put the Host entry for lcy_docker1.example from where you are pushing the image. Also make sure that while tagging image specify the registry port also.
eg: docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
docker tag ubuntu 52.203.56.158:5000/ubuntu:v3
docker push 52.203.56.158:5000/ubuntu:v3

Comment: Why isn't port https 443? I defined the port 443 as service. @Savio Mathew

Comment: @YOUNGWANT that was just example. if you make a host entry the issue what you were report will be resolved.